# how to use str_repalce to repalce string inside function?

Tags: php, function, str-replace

this assignment is solved , but i really not know why some people here are aggressive with new developers and just press the down arrow to reduce reputation points ?
#####################

I have assignment to write a php function to replace in a string with specific word and return true if any replace occurred, otherwise return false
o Function take two parameters ( string , word )

i write this simple code :

```
    $artical = "i am php developer" ; 

function check ($word, $new_word,$artical  ) { 

 str_replace ($word , $new_word , $artical , $i ) ;

if ($i > 1 ) { 

    echo " replace is done" ;
}else { 
    echo " no replace is done" ;

}

}

check ('developer' , 'magic' , $artical) ;
```

but it always gives me "no replace is done " .

can please tell me what is wrong ?

Comment: Did you try to check the **actual result** of replace?

Comment: @YourCommonSense yes , it replace word , but $i not effective or change

Comment: @YourCommonSense , ok i understand the error when i set if ($i > 0 ) { }

Answer (score 0):

The "str_replace" method replaces all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string. It takes 3 parameters: "Search", "Replace" and "Subject", and an optional parameter "Count".

The search term is $word, the replace term is $new_word and the subject term is "i am a php developer". The count will return the number of words that have been replaced.

Your if statement `if ($i > 1 )` returns "no replace is done" if i = 1. It should be changed to  `if ($i > 0 )`.

Your code is successfully replacing the string $artical, but your if statement is giving you the wrong information.

Comment: thanks Abhishek Shivakumar , i got it .

Answer (score -2):

it solved by change if ($i > 1 ) to if ($i > 0 )

```
$artical = "i am php developer" ; 

function check ($word, $new_word,$artical  ) { 

 str_replace ($word , $new_word , $artical , $i ) ;

if ($i > 1 ) { 

    echo " replace is done" ;
}else { 
    echo " no replace is done" ;

}

}

check ('developer' , 'magic' , $artical) ;
```